# Symfony - Preprod git, cache, assets

Tags: git, deployment, symfony, production-environment

I have a Symfony 2.1 project installed in a pre-prod server with a default remote pulling the master branch of a "ref" repository.

I'd like to give my git developers the ability check their modifications in this pre-prod (staging) instance before I pull them into prod.

So on this pre-prod my devs should have the permissions to

- pull from the ref
- clear the cache
- install the assets

What are the good practices to manage it ?

Comment: you mean like each dev has a branch and need to checkout that and review it or something on the lines of continuous integration?

Comment: It is more on a continuous integration that would also allow for example to show functionalities to the client for validation. Maybe the developpers will also need to be able to merge their branch on this instance.

Comment: Have you tried jenkins? http://jenkins-ci.org/